# How to calculate Highschool average for admission?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, average, jlist

I want to calculate the high school average for admission. The user will enter lets say 75 as his/her high school average. Then the system will **output Smith, average=87, York-admitted, McGill-rejected, UofT- rejected.**

The user will input average mark into a textfield and choose at least 3 universities from a JList object. When he/she hits submit, it allows the user to enter the input data coming from textfields and JList object into an array with maximum 100 Student objects.

Class Student encapsulates the student information relevant for universities admission: student name, high school average and 3 universities chosen

I'm not quiet sure how to produce this part of the output **York-admitted, McGill-rejected, UofT- rejected.****

| University | HighSchool average for admission |
| --- | --- |
| Toronto | 90 |
| York | 84 |
| Brock | 75 |
| McGill | 76 |

I thought about creating an array of marks as such:

```
private int grades[] = {90,84,75,76,88,90,78,82,80};

for (int grd: grades)
   if(mark > grade.length) // But I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.
```

Part of my current code is below.

```
//My student class
    class Student
{
   private String fName;
   private int mark;
   private String uni1, uni2, uni3;
      
   public Student(String n, int m, String u1, String u2, String u3)
   {
      fName = n;
      mark = m;
      uni1 = u1;
      uni2 = u2;
      uni3 = u3;
      
   }
   
   public String getName()
   {
      return fName;
   }
   
   public int getMark()
   {
      return mark;
   }
   
   public String getUni()
   {
      // should I create my cases here to compare the marks?
      return 0;
   }
   public String toString()
   {
      return fName + "," + "average=" + mark + getUni() + "\n";
   }

}
  
     // handle button events
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
        {
             String s1 ="";
              String s2 = "";
              String uList;
              
              
              
              if (event.getSource() == b1) // the submit button
              {
                 s1=t1.getText();
                 s2=t2.getText();   // retrieve the average mark 
                 int mark = Integer.parseInt(s2); 
                 uList = universityList.getSelectedValue().toString();
                 st[count++] = new Student(getName(), mark);
                 t1.setText("");
                 t2.setText("");
                 l4.setText("Student" + count + "out of 100");
              }
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you can add an example `input` and `output` it might really help to understand your problem. If I understand correctly I think you are trying to identify which university did the given student got admitted to. For that you will need a data structure to hold university marks and compare it back with user input student average. Also I'm not really sure if this question feeds the guidelines of stackoverflow, you might want to check that as well

Comment: you have clarified my question perfectly. I'm just not clear on to write the code to make the comparison. For example the user would enter his average as 75 and the output should be **York-admitted, McGill-rejected, UofT- rejected**. I'm just a beginner here trying to learn and looking for advice...Thanks.